# svn : Can not Parse lock / entries hashfile

Tags: svn, smartsvn

Whenever I am trying to lock or unlock any file in the project it gives me error :

svn :  Can not Parse lock / entries hashfile

Now I am not able to take lock on file.

Some clues : 
1. We have just migrated our svn repositories from one url to other url

Is there any way I can reset the lock file of repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible your repository was damaged in the migration (though check the working copy first, as [Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831295/svn-can-not-parse-lock-entries-hashfile/1834356#1834356) suggests — never mess with your repo's innards unless you have no other choice).  If so, you can "manually expire" all locks on the repository by deleting the `<root>/db/locks` folder.

This will not affect your repo's contents, but **will** destroy **all** lock data.  Also be aware that, if your repo's lock data got corrupted, it's entirely possible that other data did as well.  Keep the pre-migration backups around.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a corrupted working copy. (Missing/corrupted files in the .svn subdirectory of your project).

I would recommend verifying the issue with another subversionclient (E.g. TortoiseSVN or the svn client), and then checking out a new working copy.

Comment: @Bert : Thanks for suggestions.. I have checked it using Smartsvn, TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN. My all repos are working very fine.. Only the lock/unlock was not working.